# Error 500 While Passing Handsontable Data into ASP.NET Function Using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm encountering Error 500 Internal Error while Posting Handsontable Data into ASP.NET Code Behind function using Ajax. I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Please Help.

My Ajax Code:

```
function SaveData() {
            // Check What's Getting Updated
            for(var i in changedData){
                console.log(changedData[i]);
            }

            // Ajax Call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "StudentHandsOn.aspx/SaveData",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(changedData),

                success: function (changes) {
                    console.log('Data Updated: '+changedData);
                },
                error: function (thrownError) {
                    alert("Error" + thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
```

And My C# CodeBehind is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveData(List<Student> students)
{
    StudentHandsOn handsOn = new StudentHandsOn();

    handsOn.displayMessage();
}

public void displayMessage()
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Function Called.... Working Fine ');</script>");
}
```

I've Checked For What's There in the ChangedData Array Using the for Loop in SaveData and is running fine.

```
["st_01", "Albert              ", 3, "CE                  ", "Angela              ", 70, 90, 90, 250, 83.33333333333333, "B    "] StudentHandsOn.aspx:218
["st_02", "Inger               ", 2, "CE                  ", "Angela              ", 67, 98, 99, 264, 88, "B    "] StudentHandsOn.aspx:218
```

POST http://localhost:53600/StudentHandsOn.aspx/SaveData 500 (Internal Server Error)

Update:

I've added a few lines to my code:

```
var studentData = JSON.stringify(changedData) ;

console.log(studentData);
```

And Changed the Parameter type in SaveData method to List. I'm getting Output in the console as.

```
[["st_01","Albert              ",3,"CE                  ","Angela              ",70,90,90,250,83.33333333333333,"B    "],["st_02","Inger               ",2,"CE                  ","Angela              ",67,98,99,264,88,"B    "],["st_03","Hamlet              ",1,"EE                  ","Emily               ",60,60,60,180,60,"D    "],["st_04","Jiny                ",4,"CS                  ","Vannila             ",100,80,70,250,83.33333333333333,"B    "]] StudentHandsOn.aspx:218
```

POST http://localhost:53600/StudentHandsOn.aspx/SaveData 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm getting an array of arrays now. How do I pass this tothe code behind method?

Answer (score -1):

Try change serialize data code to:

```
data: '{"students": "' +  JSON.stringify(changedData) + '"}',
```

Comment: Nopes @OnitCz its not working, It tried it even earlier. Is there anything wrong with the type of arguments i'm giving in the code-behind method (List<Student>) ????

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong is something else. 
Please, paste declaration of Student class .

Comment: [Table("Student")]
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Current_Year { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public string Assignee { get; set; }
    public float Elective_1 { get; set; }
    public float Elective_2 { get; set; }
    public float Elective_3 { get; set; }
    public float Summative { get; set; }
    public float Average { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

Comment: Class Student hasn't got a attribute [Serializable].